# How do I source a shell script for Node Version Manager?

Tags: bash, bashrc, .profile, nodejs

Hi and thanks for looking!

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu, but I have set up an Ubuntu box on which to run Node.js.
I have had moderate success, but now I need to be able to easily upgrade my version of Node.
Many folks recommend using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). 
I followed the directions, but when I try to do something like this:

```
nvm ls
```

I get a messaging stating that

```
No command NVM found
```

I have gone back to check the steps I followed to install NVM, but there is one part that is tricky for may and I think to be the culprit: sourcing the file for bash.

From the instructions:

> To activate nvm, you need to source it from your bash shell
>
> `. ~/nvm/nvm.sh`

I always add this line to my `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`
file to have it automatically sources upon login. Often I also put in
a line to use a specific version of node.
So which file should I add this to?  I am guessing `profile` since it's Ubuntu?

Also, where in the file do I add this line?  After I have added this line, do I need to reboot or anything?

Any help would be deeply appreciated--especially if you can show me an example `profile` file with `. ~/nvm/nvm.sh` integrated so that I can see usage.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: If you put the line in your `.bashrc` you did everything right. If it didn't work I assume, that your installation of `nvm` is not in the directory `~/nvm`. Can you tell where you installed nvm?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

1. Open the file `vim /etc/profile`
2. insert the following lines, customize it for your own

`$ . ~/nvm/nvm.sh`

`$ nvm use 0.8.13`

Now, the nvm shell script runs through each time you log in.

hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

After installing nvm using [the installation script approach](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script), I had to source my `.bachrc` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now the `nvm` command should work:

```
me@computer:/$ nvm --version
0.26.0
```